# When should you use git rebase?

Tags: git

I, I am learning git and working on a project. I still don't quite get under what situation should you use git rebase vs git merge? What's the different usage/scenario of these 2 methods?

Comment: Welcome in the religious war of git

Comment: `rebase` gives you a clean, easy-to-follow linear history.  `merge` gives you separate commits that show resolved conflicts.  Personally I prefer `merge` for long-lasting feature branches and `rebase` for everything else.

Comment: If you have a team, ask the team. Do it their way. If you don't have a team, read, form your own opinion, then do it that way.

Comment: `rebase` vs `merge` is the wrong way to think about this, it's not either or. There are situations where `rebase` makes sense, and situations where `merge` makes sense. If you only do one or the other, it doesn't work well. You have to understand how the underlying repository works. There is an objective way to answer this, unfortunately the question closed while I was writing up the situations. [This answer may help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40641146/what-are-the-conceptual-differences-between-merging-stashing-and-rebasing-in-gi/40641519#40641519).