# 'git log' does not match up with 'git log tag..'

Tags: git, git-commit, git-log

I've always assumed that 'git log' is the source of all truth, showing things truly chronologically. But I've run into a contradiction with the git log range option. I believed that the 'tag..' option would give me everything between a tag and HEAD on the specific branch I'm on.

For example, I use `git log --oneline --decorate` and get

```
df43779 (HEAD -> myBranch) commit o
5aeb672 commit n
34cc390 (tag: myTag) commit k
060e7ee commit i
7b6607a commit f
08a3fea commit d
467aea3 commit b
aa4c5dd commit a
```

And I would expect that when I do `git log myTag.. --oneline --decorate` I would get

```
af43779 (HEAD -> myBranch) commit o
5aeb672 commit n
```

However, when I run `git log myTag.. --oneline --decorate` I am getting this instead:

```
df43779 (HEAD -> myBranch) commit o
5aeb672 commit n
060e7ee commit i
08a3fea commit d
```

Assuming `git log` is telling the truth, what are some reasons why my range command might be giving me commits that are out of my specified commit range?

I know some more information might be useful to answer this question specifically, such as commit times and information on branch complexity. But I guess what I really want to know is more theoretical: does the git log display things in a true chronological fashion or is it not as simple as it seems? And is the 'tag..' option doing something other than my simple explanation of what it did? What are some reasons why the examples didn't match up as I thought?

In other words, what log is the "true log" and why?

Comment: Git history is not linear. Unfortunately, `git log` by default makes up a linear history. Add `--graph` to see how the commits are connected, that is the "true log".

Comment: Besides what Schwern mentioned (which is true), there's another issue with `git log`: it *intentionally* hides commits. See, e.g., the "viewing" and "viewing commits" sections of chapter 5 (starting at p. 87) [here](http://web.torek.net/torek/tmp/book.pdf).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git log myTag..` is really `git log myTag..HEAD`. It's asking for all the commits reachable from `HEAD` ***excluding*** those reachable from `myTag`. This answers the question "what have I done since `myTag`?" See [gitrevisions](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions) "Dotted Range Notations".

`o` and `n` are obvious, they're after `myTag`. But why `i` and `d` which seem to be before `myTag`? It's hard to know from just your `git log`. `git log` presents a linear view of history, but Git history is not linear. Branches are real and commits can be connected in multiple ways.

By default, `git log` presents history in *reverse chronological order* while also making sure that parents and children are also in the right order. You'd have to run `git log --graph` to see the true connections. Make a habit of using it, or a Git log visualizer like [`tig`](https://github.com/jonas/tig).

Here is one way this could happen...

```
        o HEAD
        |
        n
        |\
  myTag k |
        | i
        f |
        | d
        |/
        b
        |
        a
```

The reverse-date order is still `o-n-k-i-f-d-b-a`, but now we see a branch was made at `b` and merged at `n`. `myTag` can't see `o-n` ahead of it, but it also can't see `i-d` in the other branch. `myTag` and `HEAD`'s history come back together at `b`. So `git log myTag..HEAD` gives you `o-n-i-d`.

Comment: Thanks. I double checked with `--graph` and you were correct. Does matter if I use rebasing instead of merging in terms of what the logs will show?

Comment: @JCollier Yes, very much so. `git merge foo` merges two branches, as above. `git rebase foo` "moves" your commits (really it writes new commits) on top of `foo`. It's like pretending your commits were written on top of `foo` all along. In general, `rebase` to update a branch with its parent, `merge` when you're done. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40641146/what-are-the-conceptual-differences-between-merging-stashing-and-rebasing-in-gi/40641519#40641519