# Github "Squash and Merge" - subsequent pull request showing all previous changes

Tags: git, github, squash

I have a branch which I pulled from master branch. Let's call it integration.

In the integration branch, I made various commits (C1, C2, C3). When I am done, I made a Pull Request to the master branch. From the master branch, I did a "Squash and Merge" so it results in only a single commit in the master. This all seems great.

But then later, I made some additional changes to the integration branch and when I make a pull request again, I am seeing all the commit comments of previous changes (C1, C2, C3, C4) that I have already committed. This issue is not seen if I use the default "Create an Merge commit" in my earlier commit. What did I do wrong?

Comment: I think this reply might help you. But instead of branches, you'll have to find the common-ancestor yourself. https://stackoverflow.com/a/70994400/1759443

Answer (score 19):

It's easier to understand visually. Here's your repo. `master` is at commit `B`, and your `feature` branch is at commit `C3`.

```
A - B [master]
     \
      C1 - C2 - C3 [feature]
```

A normal merge does this. A new merge commit, `BC123`, is added combining the content in `master` with those in `feature`. The histories are linked together. Note that `feature` does not move, it's still at `C3`.

```
A - B ------------- BC123 [master]
     \            /
      C1 - C2 - C3 [feature]
```

A squash and merge does this.

```
A - B ------------- BC123 [master]
     \
      C1 - C2 - C3 [feature]
```

`BC123` contains the same merged content as before, but there's no connection to the `feature` branch. And again, `feature` does not change. `feature` does not get squashed, it sticks around. Instead `BC123` contains the squashed changes from `feature`.

When you did more work on `feature`, commits `C4` and `C5` here, this happened.

```
A - B ------------- BC123 [master]
     \
      C1 - C2 - C3 - C4 - C5 [feature]
```

And when you issue a pull request, all the changes in `feature` not in `master` will appear. As far as Git is concerned that's `C1` to `C5`. If you were to squash & merge again, there would be a new commit on `master`, but only with the content of C4 and C5 because Git is pretty good at figuring out duplicate content between branches.

```
A - B ------------- BC123 - C45 [master]
     \
      C1 - C2 - C3 - C4 - C5 [feature]
```

While you *can* work this way, it's confusing.

Long story short: once you merge a branch, don't work on it anymore. Delete it. If you need to do more work open a new branch.

> *This issue is not seen if I use the default "Create an Merge commit" in my earlier commit.*

Going back to the merged version...

```
A - B ------------- BC123 [master]
     \            /
      C1 - C2 - C3 [feature]
```

If you do more work on `feature`...

```
A - B ------------- BC123 [master]
     \            /
      C1 - C2 - C3 - C4 - C5 [feature]
```

And then do a pull request, Git will show you the commits in `feature` which are not in `master`. Because of the merge, `master` contains `C1`, `C2`, and `C3`. So the PR only shows you `C4` and `C5`. This is still confusing, and the same advice applies: once you merge a branch, delete it. Open another one if you need to do more work.

While squash & merge is simpler, merging (done right) provides a healthier history and more information for Git to work from. You'll get more out of Git if you understand how branching and merging works.

Comment: Maybe I am being naive. The difference in the 2 illustrated merge example is really just the merge arrow. Isn't it possible to do booth squash-and-merge and add a merge arrow? There is definitely value in squash and merge.

Comment: @someuser: yes, the difference is "just" the merge arrow.  But that's a huge difference: it changes the *merge base* (of the later merge), which is one of the three inputs to the merge-as-a-verb action. Use a different merge base and you get a different merge result.

Comment: @someuser A "squash & merge" with the merge arrow is a normal merge. Git history is not linear and it confuses people (mostly Git's fault for `git log` faking a linear history by default). If you're using squash & merge to get a simpler, linear history there's [better ways to accomplish that without losing fidelity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40641146/what-are-the-conceptual-differences-between-merging-stashing-and-rebasing-in-gi/40641519#40641519). Unfortunately Github does not currently support this, you have to do it manually.

Comment: @Schwern, in the first example (squash & merge), if I decided to not use squash & merge with the 2nd PR (C4-C5) but instead use standard merge, what will happen? Will the master look like `BC123--C4-C5` and then my branch will become current with master?

Comment: @someuser  `master` would add a merge commit with `BC123` and `C5` as its parents. `feature` would remain at `C5`. Merging only updates the branch doing the merging. The other branch is left alone. When you `git merge feature` from `master` only `master` changes. `feature` is left unchanged.

Answer (score 7):

If I'm understanding your situation correct...

The main thing you're doing wrong is continuing to use a branch after it has been merged. After you merge, delete the branch. Additional work should be on a new branch.

The first "Squash and Merge" does not affect the integration branch; just how the integrated commits appear on the master branch. So, it makes sense that A, B, & C would still be there since you are reusing the old branch.

Good luck.

Comment: The real issue is the same problem exists between PR of 2 repos (one being the fork of another). I would have to delete the repo to avoid the old commits showing up in my next PR.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. I think you should be able to create a new branch from master, where C1, C2, & C3 are already merged. So, you'd just need to cherry-pick C4 into the new branch and open a PR.

Comment: I was referring to having 2 different repos. If I did the development on fork's master and used it to generate PR. I would run into the same issue after a squash and merge. Now I have additional changes in master that I need to merge to forked parent. Cherry-pick seems like a lot of work when there are merge conflict involved.